# click work's incorrect, it add class to a tag, then remove it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i try to make click effect on category
here is my jquery code:

```
$('document').ready(function() {
        $('.links a').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('.links a').removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');
        });
    });
```

and html:

```
<div class ="links">
        <a id="section-<?=$arParams['CODE']?>-link" href="#" onclick="ajax_load('#no-scroll-items-<?=$arParams['CODE'];?>', '<?=$arResult['AJAX_CALL_ID']?>', 'do=select_section&id=<?=4610?>'); return false;" class="" title="Мобильные телефоны">Мобильные телефоны</a>
        <a id="section-<?=$arParams['CODE']?>-link" href="#" onclick="ajax_load('#no-scroll-items-<?=$arParams['CODE'];?>', '<?=$arResult['AJAX_CALL_ID']?>', 'do=select_section&id=<?=4611?>'); return false;" class="" title="Планшеты">Планшеты</a>
        <a id="section-<?=$arParams['CODE']?>-link" href="#" onclick="ajax_load('#no-scroll-items-<?=$arParams['CODE'];?>', '<?=$arResult['AJAX_CALL_ID']?>', 'do=select_section&id=<?=4616?>'); return false;" class="" title="Монопады">Монопады</a>
        <a id="section-<?=$arParams['CODE']?>-link" href="#" onclick="ajax_load('#no-scroll-items-<?=$arParams['CODE'];?>', '<?=$arResult['AJAX_CALL_ID']?>', 'do=select_section&id=<?=4630?>'); return false;" class="" title="Наушники">Наушники</a>
        <a id="section-<?=$arParams['CODE']?>-link" href="#" onclick="ajax_load('#no-scroll-items-<?=$arParams['CODE'];?>', '<?=$arResult['AJAX_CALL_ID']?>', 'do=select_section&id=<?=4739?>'); return false;" class="" title="Медиаплееры">Медиаплееры</a>
        <a id="section-<?=$arParams['CODE']?>-link" href="#" onclick="ajax_load('#no-scroll-items-<?=$arParams['CODE'];?>', '<?=$arResult['AJAX_CALL_ID']?>', 'do=select_section&id=<?=4593?>'); return false;" class="" title="Аксессуары">Аксессуары</a>
    </div>
```

it work's incorrect 
here is an example:
http://jsfiddle.net/fDZ97/
what I missed?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking, it seems to work fine. What effect are you trying to achieve?

Comment: well, It adding class to an a statement, after remove it, I need just add class, and remove on another click

Comment: try selection `$('.links a').not(this).removeClass('active');`

Comment: FYI, there is no element of type `document` in the DOM. Your code is equivalent to `$().ready(handler);` which shouldn't be used, not using internally readyPromise

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are asking is toggle

```js
$(function() {
  var $links = $('#links a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $links.not(this).removeClass('active');
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
  });
});

function Animate2id(id) {
    // your function stuff
}
```

```css
.active {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="links">
  <a class="active" href="#" onClick="Animate2id('#box1');">Content 1</a>
  <a href="#" onClick="Animate2id('#box2');">Content 2</a>
  <a href="#" onClick="Animate2id('#box3');">Content 3</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is your working code:

```
$('document').ready(function() {
    $('#links a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if($(this).hasClass("active")){
            $(this).removeClass('active');
        }else{
            $('#links a').removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');
        }  
    });
});
```

[Here is the JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fDZ97/43/)

From what I understood, you simply want to add the *active* class on click, then remove it when clicked again. Therefore the above should work for you.